# Adjusting width to ellipsed content

Tags: html, css

I am displaying some text in a `span` element contained in a fixed width structure using ellipsis if said text overflows. A Boostrap tooltip is initialized in such elements so that the full text can be visualized. However the full width of the `span` visually misplaces the tooltip. How can I adjust its width so that the tooltip is rendered in a proper position?

Below a working snippet ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kpagcha/ofbvc0sk/1/) link).

```js
$('.venue').tooltip({
  placement: 'right',
  container: 'body'
});
```

```css
@import("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css") .round {
  margin: 40px 20px;
  background: #ededed;
  width: 150px;
}

.match {
  height: 190x;
  position: relative;
}

.team {
  width: 155px;
  height: 22px;
  background: #eee;
  position: relative;
}

.label {
  width: 120px;
  position: absolute;
}

.score {
  width: 35px;
  float: right;
}

.scheduling {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 23px;
}

.scheduling>.wrapper {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="round">
  <div class="match">
    <div class="team">
      <div class="label">Team 1</div>
      <div class="score">0</div>
      <div class="scheduling">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <span class="date">24/10/2019</span> &mdash;
          <span class="venue" title="Very Long Venue Name">Very Long Venue Name</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just converted your code sample into a working snippet (fiddle link preserved, but let its code "as is" there).

Comment: Do you stick to a `tooltip` solution? It might not fit well your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first proposal:

```
.scheduling > .wrapper {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
.venue {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

My second proposal: deplace title

```
 <div class="wrapper" title="Very Long Venue Name">
      <span class="date">24/10/2019</span>
      &mdash;
      <span class="venue" >Very Long Venue Name</span>
    </div>
```

and

```
$('.wrapper').tooltip({placement: 'right', container: 'body'});
```

Comment: That's no good because technically `.date` could also have a tooltip. The venue tooltip must be displayed relative to the venue `span`, not the wrapper.

Comment: like this ? [link](https://jsfiddle.net/sfkxon2r/) Each tooltip is relatived to its span